# Why i got error "The system cannot find the path specified." in subprocess python

Tags: python, subprocess, command-prompt, os.system

```
import subprocess
import os
....
....
opn=open(ak,'w')
tt=txt.get(1.0,END)
opn.write(tt)
lst=[]
for i in range(0,len(ak)):
    if ak[i]=='/':
        lst.append(i)
    else:
        pass
val=lst[-1]+1
path=ak
file_name=path[val:]
sudo_path_name=path[3:val-1]
dir_name=path[:2]
path_name="cd "
for i in sudo_path_name:
    if i=='/':
        path_name+='\\'
    else:
        path_name+=i
command=dir_name+'&&'+path_name+'&&'+file_name
os.system(command)
output = subprocess.getoutput(command)
print(output)
```

ak is path of a file
My aim is just print the output when ak execute..
But whenever I tried to execute it give output as

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

When i get command and run with commmand prompt it executes successfully with no error..
Thank You

Comment: Which line specifically results in the "cannot find path" error?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the full error traceback.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: try `/full/path/to/file`. Code may run in different folder then you expect. And it may run with different system settings and with different privileges.

Comment: I don't understand why you run the same code two times - `os.system()` and `subprocess.getoutput()`. You need only `subprocess.getoutput()`

Comment: when you run `subprocess` without `shell=True` then you have to use list `[dir_name, '&&', path_name, '&&', file_name]`. But without `shell=True` it may not understand `&&` - so you have to run it with `shell=True`. Besided without `shell=True` it may not understand command `cd`.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the editor. It happened to me too I used VS-code but when I changed cwd it worked! So it may be that problem.
Also try putting the full path or try this code:-

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os
os.chdir(Path(__file__).parent)
```